# its a exercise with a solution plz explain me a if statement in this

Tags: python-3.x

```py
hours = int(input("Enter the hours: "))
rate = float(input("Enter the rate: "))

if hours > 40:
    pay = (hours - 40) * rate * 1.5 + 40 * rate
else:
    pay = hours * rate

print("pay: ", pay)
```

Answer (score 1):

If hours greater than 40

```
if hours > 40: 
    pay = (hours - 40) * rate * 1.5 + 40 * rate
```

If hours less than or equal to 40

```
else: 
    pay = hours * rate
```